# SQL Select/Join, LIMIT result to 1st entry per element in query list

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query like so

```
Select * from tableA A 
LEFT JOIN
mydb.tableB B
ON A.pk = B.tableA_pk 
LEFT JOIN 
mydb.tableC C    
ON B.tableC_pk = C.pk
WHERE C.PK  IN ('325','305', '322')
ORDER BY A.pk desc;
```

This will return a result like so with potentially multiple rows for an entry where applicable

```
4, xxx, yyy, 325, 325, zzz <<<< most recent for this entry ( 'unique' key is tableC.pk, 325)
3, aaa, bbb, 325, 325, eee <<<< next most recent 
3, ccc, ddd, 322, 322, fff
2, eee, fff, 305, 305, rrr 
2, ggg, hhhh,322, 322, ttt
1, iii, jjj, 325, 325, uuu <<< oldest
```

Ideally i want the result to look like below, that is for each matching entry in the LIST ..IN ('325', '322') it should only return the most recent entry like below

```
4, xxx, yyy, 325, 325, zzz <<<< most recent
3, ccc, ddd, 322, 322, fff
2, eee, fff, 305, 305, rrr
```

To explain further..

```
Select * from tableA A 
LEFT JOIN
mydb.tableB B
ON A.pk = B.tableA_pk 
LEFT JOIN 
mydb.tableC C    
ON B.tableC_pk = C.pk
WHERE C.PK  IN ('325')
ORDER BY A.pk desc;
```

I would get this

```
4, xxx, yyy, 325, 325, zzz <<<< most recent for this entry 
3, aaa, bbb, 325, 325, eee <<<< next most recent 
1, iii, jjj, 325, 325, uuu <<< oldest
```

But I need this:

```
4, xxx, yyy, 325, 325, zzz <<<< most recent for this entry ( 'unique' key is tableC.pk)
```

I have tried LIMIT 1 (I'm using MySQL) like below but this limits to 1 for the total request not 1 per searched entry in my query list.

```
Select * from tableA A 
LEFT JOIN
mydb.tableB B
ON A.pk = B.tableA_pk 
LEFT JOIN 
mydb.tableC C    
ON B.tableC_pk = C.pk
WHERE C.pk  IN ('325','305', '322')
ORDER BY A.pk desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Well you can achieve it using Row_Number() function with Partition By Clause.

Comment: If you provide adequate information on your table structure and some sample data I'll tell you how to do this.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I don't think MySQL has those.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Comment: Can you create the schema in [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) ? So that we can help you betterly.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column/25694562#25694562

Comment: @Bulat Yes, a correlated subquery is one way to solve this.

Comment: a correlated subquery is probably the *best* way to solve this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading suggestions and other answers I achieved it like so..many thanks for all help....

```
SELECT
DISTINCT C.PK
,B.PK
,B.tableC_pk
,B.tableA_pk
,A.pk

FROM

tableC C
INNER JOIN
tableB B
ON C.PK = B.tableC_pk
INNER JOIN
tableA A
ON A.PK = B.tableA_pk

INNER JOIN ( SELECT tableC_pk,MAX(PK) AS PK FROM tableB
WHERE tableC_pk IN ('325','322','111')
GROUP BY 1) D
ON C.PK = B.tableC_pk
AND B.PK = D.PK
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable by iterating it with 1 like so.

```
Select A.*, @i:=@i+1 AS rownum
from tableA A 
LEFT JOIN
mydb.tableB B
ON A.pk = B.tableA_pk 
LEFT JOIN 
mydb.tableC C    
ON B.tableC_pk = C.pk
WHERE C.PK IN ('325') and (SELECT @i:= 0) r
ORDER BY A.pk desc;
```

**Note:** I have not tested above query.

Answer (score -1):

This question is asked several times a day. Here you will find an answer:

[SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column/25694562#25694562)

Comment: I flagged it as duplicate.

Comment: Oh ok. Then why post an answer? My understanding is that questions that should be closed aren't supposed to be answered.

Comment: I guess. I have flagged several questions like this and none of them was closed, so I just answer with the link, if it gets accepted it will only confirm that its a dupe. Or author can remove the question, that will be even better.